# How to export data in scientific form

Tags: export, data

I am having an issue about how to export data in its scientific form using *Mathematica*.

To be concrete, I define a list

```
alist = {2344. 1111111, 0.0002223344};
ScientificForm[%]
Export["test.dat", %]
```

but it turns out that doesn't work. Is there any other way to achieve this? Also, what can I do to control the number of digits exported?

Any idea?

Answer (score 8):

```
Export["test.dat",
   NumberForm[
     alist, 
     NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "E", #3}] &), 
     ExponentFunction -> (3 Quotient[#, 3] &)
   ], 
   "Table"
]

(*   ==> {2.34411E3, 222.334E-6} *)
```

Comment: I thought a similar thing is possible with CForm but I failed to set it as Listable.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries Why doesn't this work with `DecimalForm` ?