# Export of data to text file in exponential form

Tags: list-manipulation, export, formatting

I have seen the answer [How to export data in scientific form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43199/how-to-export-data-in-scientific-form) but it is only partly helping me.

I have the `list` of data which I want to export in a formatted form to a file. In addition I want to prepend a header.

What I tried:

```
list = {0.004,0.00273904,0.00447323,0.00344523,0.00327233,0.00375527,0.055290,0.008,0.00273586,0.00446845,0.00344505,0.00327311,0.00376325,0.06050960,0.012,0.00273243,0.00446187,0.00344387,0.00327414,0.00377089,0.06586520,0.016,0.0027274,0.00445676,0.00344366,0.00327586,0.00377908,0.07112480,0.02,0.00272475,0.004451,0.00344402,0.0032789,0.0037872,0.07636090,0.024,0.0027227,0.00444807,0.00344451,0.00328181,0.0037949,0.081729};

formatted = Partition[Map[NumberForm[#, {12, 9}] &, list], 7];
header = {"       time          x1          y1          x2          y2          x3          y3"};
output = Prepend[formatted, header];

Export["data.txt", output, "Table"];
```

The content of the file is:

```
       time          x1          y1          x2          y2          x3          y3
0.004000000 0.002739043 0.004473226 0.003445232 0.003272333 0.003755268 0.05529000
0.008000000 0.002735863 0.004468450 0.003445050 0.003273114 0.003763252 0.06050960
0.012000000 0.002732431 0.004461866 0.003443870 0.003274136 0.003770894 0.06586520
0.016000000 0.002727400 0.004456763 0.003443659 0.003275864 0.003779077 0.07112480
0.020000000 0.002724752 0.004450998 0.003444017 0.003278901 0.003787201 0.07636090
0.024000000 0.002722704 0.004448069 0.003444513 0.003281807 0.003794901 0.08172900
```

I have two questions:

a. How can I prepend the header more elegantly?

b. How can I export the data in exponential form whereby each number should have the same form (same number of digits before the comma, another same number of digits after the comma) e.g.:

```
0.004000000 -> 4.000000E-3

...

0.081729000 -> 8.172900E-2
```

I expect that there must be a Mathematica built in solution to do the upper formatting instead of writing own functions.

Comment: Maybe `Dataset` can help you

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19387/2079

Comment: @george2079: May be I am missing something: with your answering code in the upper link I cannot convert `0.00711248` to `7.11248E-3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually I think this is all you need.

```
NumberForm[0.081729000, {6, 6},
     NumberSigns -> {"-", " "},
     ExponentFunction -> (# &), 
     NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "E", #3}] &)]
```

> 8.172900E-2

I think the first number in `{6,6}` does nothing here by the way.

If you really want everything aligned regardless of signs of exponents it takes a bit more effort:

```
StringPadLeft["", 1];  (*this must be evaluated first for no evident reason*)
fixedform[numd_, data_] := Module[{ef},
  ef[s_String /; StringTake[s, 1] == "-"] := 
   "-" <> StringPadLeft[StringTake[s, {2, -1}], 2, "0"];
  ef[s_String] := "+" <> StringPadLeft[s, 2, "0"];
  NumberForm[data, {numd, numd},
   ExponentFunction -> (# &), 
   NumberSigns -> {"-", " "}, 
   NumberFormat :> (Row[{StringPadRight[#1, numd + 2, "0"], "E", 
        ef[#3]}] &)]]

 fixedform[6, 
   Grid[RandomReal[{-20, 20}, {5, 5}] 10^
      RandomReal[{-20, 20}, {5, 5}] ]]
```

[image]

Edit: pre-loading `StringPadLeft` is needed due to this bug: [Strange Error on Fresh Kernel (10.2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91567/strange-error-on-fresh-kernel-10-2)

Comment: This is great ... thanks a lot. When I call `fixedform[6, list]` (my data above) everything is perfect, only always a minus sign appears.

Comment: oops, I had `NumberSigns` reversed, should be: `NumberSigns -> {"-", " "}`