# strange `StringPadLeft` error

Tags: output-formatting

has anybody seen this?

```
$Version
NumberForm[N@Pi, {10, 6},
 ExponentFunction -> (# &),
 NumberFormat -> (Row[{StringPadLeft[#1, 10, "0"], "E", #3}] &)]
```

> "10.1.0  for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)"
>
> Get::noopen: Cannot open C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.1\SystemFiles\Components\GeneralUtilities\Kernel\64.000000Bit\GeneralUtilities.mx. >>
>
> StringPadLeft[3.141593,10.000000,0]E0

If I invoke `StringPadLeft` on its own first it works fine

```
(* fresh kernel*)
StringPadLeft["", 1];
NumberForm[N@Pi, {10, 6},
 ExponentFunction -> (# &),
 NumberFormat -> (Row[{StringPadLeft[#1, 10, "0"], "E", #3}] &)]
```

> 003.141593E0

came up while working on this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129114/2079

Looking closer we can see the "64" in the system file path and the integer 10 argument to `StringPadLeft` evidently and bizarrely got my `NumberForm` applied to them (!??)

Edit: I get the same result on linux (10.1.0 also)

Comment: I don't reproduce it on `"10.4.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"`.

Comment: right you are it is a dup..

Comment: @george2079 I was intimately familiar with this bug... :)

Comment: If its been fixed somebody ought to confirm that on the linked question.

Comment: @george2079 Someone will have to help out on that one. I only have 10.4 available right now and the bug is still present.